# Julia: Error reading tabular data from a txt file

Tags: julia

I have the file called `testfile.txt` in my working directory.

```
5.00000000E+06  1.00000000E+07  1.86965370E+13  2.00000000E+04
1.50000000E+07  1.00000000E+07  1.67889215E+13  2.00000000E+04
2.50000000E+07  1.00000000E+07  1.50764483E+13  2.00000000E+04
3.50000000E+07  1.00000000E+07  1.35391442E+13  2.00000000E+04
4.50000000E+07  1.00000000E+07  1.21590771E+13  2.00000000E+04
5.50000000E+07  1.00000000E+07  1.09201484E+13  2.00000000E+04
6.50000000E+07  1.00000000E+07  9.80790597E+12  2.00000000E+04
```

I want to store this tabular data in a dataframe.

```
# using necessary packages
using DataFrames, Queryverse
 
df = load("testfile.txt",
           header_exists = false) |> DataFrame
```

When I try this though, I get the error:

```
No applicable_loaders found for UNKNOWN
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

```
No applicable_loaders found for UNKNOWN
```

indicates that `load` does not know how to load the file; specifically a `.txt` file. There are two options to fix this:

1. Explicitly state that the file is `CSV`, which it does know how to load:

```
df = load(File(format"CSV", "testfile.txt"), spacedelim=true, header_exists=false) 
    |> DataFrame
```

2. Rename your data file to have a `csv` extension

```
df = load("testfile.csv", spacedelim=true, header_exists=false) |> DataFrame
```

Both will produce the output:

```
    7×4 DataFrame
     Row │ Column1  Column2  Column3     Column4
         │ Float64  Float64  Float64     Float64
    ─────┼───────────────────────────────────────
       1 │   5.0e6    1.0e7  1.86965e13  20000.0
       2 │   1.5e7    1.0e7  1.67889e13  20000.0
       3 │   2.5e7    1.0e7  1.50764e13  20000.0
       4 │   3.5e7    1.0e7  1.35391e13  20000.0
       5 │   4.5e7    1.0e7  1.21591e13  20000.0
       6 │   5.5e7    1.0e7  1.09201e13  20000.0
       7 │   6.5e7    1.0e7  9.80791e12  20000.0
```

Note the addition of the `spacedelim=true` to read space delimited values, which is what you supplied as the example data file contents.